# Page crahses if repsonse time is more

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Im using Silverlight with wcf for my application. When the page requests it goes to the service for the output. But if the response(database operation) takes a bit of time to provide the output then my silverlight page is getting crashed. Can any help me what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to set the timeout settings for the WCF service to be higher to cater for the potential delays. The timeout settings are usually set in the bindings defined in the

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
```

section of the config file.

You will need to make sure that the 'receiveTimeout' in the client config, and the 'sendTimeout' in the service config are set to appropriate values that are high enough to cater for your particular service's timings.

An example 'basicHttpBinding' for the client-side, with a 'receiveTimeout' of 1 minute, 30 seconds could look like this (the important item to note being the 'receiveTimeout'):

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBindingConfig" receiveTimeout="00:1:30">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: I have set in the web config "   <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/> . Can u give me sample code please...

Comment: What kind of binding are you using? Custom? BasicHttp?

Comment: Edited answer with a sample 'basicHttpBinding' for client-side

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I included in client config as follows"  <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IwcfOfficeConnect" receiveTimeout="00:05:30"
                    maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <security mode="None" />" but it is getting time out after 1 min

Comment: You probably also need to do something similar for the service-side config by setting the 'sendTimeout' to a specific value (default is 1 minute). If this doesn't work, try setting both client and service-side values for each of 'receiveTimeout', 'sendTimeout', 'openTimeout' and 'closeTimeout'.

Comment: Thank you so much. It will perfect how i would i prefer..... Thank you for the time and support